# The project failed to build after enable-migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

side info: I'm following the MVC 4 course on pluralsight
Problem:
I have an ASP.NET MVC4 internet application. Everything goes like thebook tells me but
after `enable-migrations` into the package-manager console i get en error:`The project 'somesite.web' failed to build`.

I deas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to build the project `somesite.web` by yourself and check the detail error.